# angular 9 intercept XHR requests to add Bearer token

Tags: angular, token, angular-http-interceptors

I want to intercept ALL xhr requests to add authentication in my Angular app, for this I add an HttpInterceptor but it's not fired for XHR requests, any idea how I can intercept these requests ??

Thank you.

***auth.interceptor.ts***

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { OktaAuthService } from '@okta/okta-angular';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private oktaAuth: OktaAuthService) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return from(this.handleAccess(request, next));
  }

  private async handleAccess(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Promise<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Only add an access token to whitelisted origins
    const allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost'];
    console.log('Intercept HTTP request to adding Bearer token');
    if (allowedOrigins.some(url => request.urlWithParams.includes(url))) {
      const accessToken = await this.oktaAuth.getAccessToken();
      if (accessToken) {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
          }
        });
      } else {
        //No token; proceed request without bearer token
        console.log('No token added to HTTP request');
        return next.handle(request).toPromise();
      }
    }
    return next.handle(request).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *" for XHR requests"*? The Angular interceptors are only invoked for requests made through the HttpClient.

Comment: Also, did you provide the interceptor in your module using the HTTP_INTERCEPTORS token?

Comment: Hi @sloth, yes I provide HTTP_INTERCEPTORS in my module.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe , XHR requests made by libraries like select2 in ajax (it not use HttpClient). Is there a way to intercept all non HttpClient requests ?? Thank you.

Comment: Not with Angular, no. Those requests are made outside of the HttpClient.